# Programmatically set margin for TableRow

Tags: android

I have `TableRows` created dynamically in the code and I want to set margins for these `TableRows`.

My `TableRows` created as follow:

```
// Create a TableRow and give it an ID
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);       
        tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        Button btnManageGroupsSubscriptions = new Button(this);
        btnManageGroupsSubscriptions.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40));

        tr.addView(btnManageGroupsSubscriptions);
        contactsManagementTable.addView(tr);
```

How do I dynamically set the margins for these?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to setup LayoutParams properly. Margin is a property of layout and not the TableRow , so you have to set the desired margins in the LayoutParams.

Heres a sample code:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);  
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

int leftMargin=10;
int topMargin=2;
int rightMargin=10;
int bottomMargin=2;

tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
```

Comment: What about a textView ? setMargins undefined for textView.

Comment: Did not work. But the answer of @mik below worked, and should have been the accepted answer

Comment: Strange, it requires double margin as much in programmatic way as manual feed in xml.

Answer (score 14):

This is working:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(...);
TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(10,10,10,10);             
tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

------

// the key is here!
yourTableLayoutInstance.addView(tr, lp);
```

You need to add your TableRow to TableLayout passing the layout parameters again!

Comment: Should have been the accepted answer. Without the last line in the answer  it does not work 'yourTableLayoutInstance.addView(tr, lp);'.