# Android dynamically give space between tablerows

Tags: android, padding, tablelayout, tablerow

I am implementing a table layout and adding table rows to it dynamically. I want give space between these rows. may I know how to do it. I am also adding a textView to the tableRow. I am declaring the table layout in the xml file. I tried giving padding inside the table row. But that seems to work within the tableRows and not between tableRows. please help.

Comment: Can you please share with us what was it that you corrected ? I am having troubles setting space between columns in a tableLayout which is within a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the top or bottom margin of rows.

Here is an example: [Programmatically set margin for TableRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577644/programmatically-set-margin-for-tablerow)

Comment: There may be something else in your layout which is preveting it, you need to experiment by starting with a simple working solution and then move to the complex final.

Comment: I am declaring only the table layout in my layout file. rest I am doing it programatically.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. As you said something else was preventing it.

Comment: @Droidme:if u share the solution ..........with us we will be happy..... i am facing the same problem trying to set margin between rows programatically...thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set the margin between rows in a table layout you need to use the following XML

```
<Tablelayout> android:stretchColumns="*" </Tablelayout >
```