# How to add space between buttons in same row

Tags: android, android-widget

I found this example

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
        layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(20,20) );

        layout.setPadding(1,1,1,1);



        for (int f=0; f<=3; f++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

            for (int c=0; c<=3; c++) {


                Button b = new Button (this);
                b.setText(""+f+c);
                b.setTextSize(10.0f);
                b.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

                b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 100, 200, 200));
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
                b.setWidth(24);
                b.setHeight(24);
                tr.addView(b);
            } // for
            layout.addView(tr);
        } // for

        super.setContentView(layout);
    } // ()
```

I need to have matrix of buttons ( something like GridLayout in Java ). The problem in this code is that I don't have any space between columns in same row. How to add space between buttons in same row ?

Comment: So when you compile this there is no padding between any of the buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set margins for your buttons, because padding may only size down the top layer of the button and not its background. Here is an example how to do something similar in code: [Programmatically set margin for TableRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577644/programmatically-set-margin-for-tablerow)

However in this example you need to change the parent container to TableRow, because layout parameters always refer to its immediate parent, which for your buttons is TableRow.