# Code to equally divide space of TableRow in Android

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I want to divide space of TableRow in Android among the children equally. Here is the screen done by me so far. [image]

I want the row of "text 1 text 1 text 1" to take equal amount of space. I want to do it from java code. My java code is as follows :

```
public class History extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int counter=0;
    TableLayout TL ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);        

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);  
    } 

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        TableLayout TL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout); 
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        counter++;

        TextView t = new TextView(this); 
        t.setText("text " + counter);

        TextView t1 = new TextView(this); 
        t1.setText("text " + counter);

        TextView t2 = new TextView(this); 
        t2.setText("text " + counter);

        // add the TextView and the CheckBox to the new TableRow

        row.addView(t);
        row.addView(t1);
        row.addView(t2);
        TL.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

I want to implement the following screen . 
[image]
What can I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: The `TableLayout` has a method `setStretchAllColumns()`.

Comment: You might find this link helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4577669/1295906

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `weight` and `weightSum` in the `TableRow` and set our `TextView` via `TableLayout.LayoutParams` to do this. Here is some example code with relevant comments:

```
 TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
 row.setLayoutParams(
     new TableLayout.LayoutParams((LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
 // Set the weightSum of the row
 row.setWeightSum(1f);

 // Set the layout and weight for the columns. Note 0.5f gives us 0.5f+0.5f = 1f,
 // the weightSum set above. (Using two rows as an example).
 TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
      new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, 
                      LayoutParams.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);

 TextView t1 = new TextView(this); 
 t1.setText("text " + counter);
 // Set our layoutParams
 t1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

 TextView t2 = new TextView(this); 
 t2.setText("text " + counter);
 // Set our layoutParams
 t2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

 // Add views to row
 row.addView(t1);
 row.addView(t2);
 // Add row to table
 TL.addView(row);
```

Comment: After pasting this code , I have seen that no row is added .

Comment: @osimer pothe Table row is child of LinearLayout, so you can use LinearLayout properties WeightSum and weight.It will solve your problem.cheers...

Comment: I have not understood your solutions .

Comment: You aren't supposed to paste the code, its an example. Have a look at this blogpost if you don't understand what Weight and WeightSum are all about: http://solution2tech.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/weightweight-sum-in-android.html